# angular-cli : Shufflejs plugin usage

Tags: angular-cli

Since there is no angular module so far, how can one implement **[Shufflejs](http://js-tutorial.com/shuffle-categorize-sort-and-filter-a-grid-of-items-671)** into a angular-cli project?

Here is my component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'proj-masonry',
    templateUrl: 'proj-masonry.component.html'
})
export class ProjMasonryComponent implements OnInit {
    ngOnInit() {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var $grid = $('#grid'),
                $sizer = $grid.find('.shuffle__sizer');

            $grid.shuffle({
                itemSelector: '.picture-item',
                sizer: $sizer
            });
        });
    }
}
```

And here is my `.angular-cli.json` script files import:

```
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "../node_modules/shufflejs/dist/shuffle.js"
],
```

The HTML within my component comes from the html part of **[this tutorial](http://js-tutorial.com/shuffle-categorize-sort-and-filter-a-grid-of-items-671)**.

I get the following error:

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: $grid.shuffle is not a function TypeError: $grid.shuffle is not a function
```

What is wrong here?

---

**EDIT:** I managed to define the property globally:

```
let Shuffle = "shuffle" in window ? window['shuffle'] : '';
```

So now the previous error is gone, but now I get another:

[image: [1]: https://vestride].github.io/Shuffle/

---

**EDIT 2:** The second error was due to duplicate import line in `.angular-cli.json`

Answer (score 0):

So a fully working module including Shufflejs would look like:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'proj-masonry',
    templateUrl: 'proj-masonry.component.html'
})
export class ProjMasonryComponent implements OnInit {
    ngOnInit() {
        let Shuffle = "shuffle" in window ? window['shuffle'] : '';

        let element = document.getElementById('grid');
        let sizer = element.querySelector('.my-sizer-element');

        let shuffle = new Shuffle(element, {
            itemSelector: '.picture-item',
            sizer: sizer,
            gutterWidth: 33,
            columnWidth: 540
        })
    }
}
```